# How to use the Cabon class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need format a string date in Laravel

My date is like `2021-05-25`

I need format this to `25/05/2021` using Carbon

Comment: In addition to these answers, here is the [Documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats) for your future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
use \Carbon\Carbon;

$birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',  '28/01/1994'); 
    
echo $birth->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```php
use \Carbon\Carbon;

$birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',  '28/01/1994'); 
    
echo $birth->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a copy-paste of the answer that somebody else gave to you, it shouldn't be posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$myDate = '2021-05-25';
$result = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $myDate)->format('Y-m-d');
echo $result;
```